# What is the default pivot in an Android View?

Tags: android

I'm trying to position some elements on my interface and can't find this info on the documentation.

In Android, what's the default pivot (X and Y) for a View?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default, the center of the view.

See [View.setPivotX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPivotX(float))

> Sets the x location of the point around which the view is rotated and
>   scaled. By default, the pivot point is centered on the object. Setting
>   this property disables this behavior and causes the view to use only
>   the explicitly set pivotX and pivotY values.

Comment: and what about the pivot values? is that .... the max is width for pivotX and viceversa?